# Резиновая шапка с помощью flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Нужно сделать шапку, чтобы при любом разрешении экрана расстояние между элементами было одинаковым.
Я решил делать с помощью flex (Может есть варианты лучше?)
Имею такой код:

```css
/* header */

.b-header {
  height: 230px;
  position: relative;
  background: asset-url("x1.png", images) repeat-x;
  z-index: 101;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.b-logo {
  left: 130px;
  top: 6px;
  position: absolute;
}

.b-second-logo {
  left: 280px;
  top: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}

.b-logo-text {
  left: 24px;
  top: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
}

.b-logo-text strong {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.b-logo-secondary-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.b-org-name {
  color: #fff;
  left: 26%;
  top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.b-org-name strong {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 29px;
  line-height: 33px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.b-org-info {
  right: 32.8%;
  top: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 17px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  background: asset-url("clock.png", images) 15px 67px no-repeat;
  //background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.b-org-info__address {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.b-org-info__hint {
  color: #ffff00;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 0px;
  left: 71px;
}
```

```html
<header class="b-header flex">
  <a href="" class="b-second-logo"></a>
  <a href="" class="b-logo"></a>

  <div class="b-logo-text">
    <strong> Заголовок </strong>
    <div class="b-logo-secondary-text">
      Заголовок 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="b-org-info">
    <div class="b-org-info__hint"> </div>
    <div class="b-org-info__address">
      Адрес
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Я так понимаю, чтобы шапка стала резиновая мне нужно присвоить ей класс `.flex`. Но ничего не меняется. Но когда я прописываю правила из класса `.flex` в класс `.b-org-info`, тогда один этот блок становится резиновым.   В общем-то  получается то поведение, которое мне нужно (немного криво элементы ставятся, но пока не об этом).

Как организовать код? и почему не срабатывает код, когда я всей шапке присваиваю класс `.flex`?

Comment: Так глаза режит позиционирование с помощью absolute. Зачем его используете? Оберните две ссылки в один div -> настройте отступ и не парьтесь с absolute. Уберите у остальных absolute и настраивайте с помощью отступа

Comment: Именно из за absolute ничего, в принципе, и не выходит

Comment: А чем плох absolute?

Comment: `absolute` вырывает элементы из потока.

Comment: на дворе уже 20й год заканчивается - пора переходить на гриды :) (удобно, и жрут меньше, чем флексы)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.b-header { border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
  height: 230px;
  position: relative;
  background: asset-url("x1.png", images) repeat-x;
  z-index: 101;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 1px hsla(0,0%,20%,6);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.b-logo { border:1px solid hsla(0,80%,50%,1);
 line-height:2;
 flex:1 1 10%;
}

.b-second-logo 
{ 
 border:1px solid hsla(0,80%,50%,1);
 line-height:2;
  flex:1 1 10%;
}

.b-logo-text 
{ 
 height:2em;
  border:1px solid hsla(240,80%,50%,1);
  color: #000;
  flex:1 1 29%;
}

.b-logo-text strong
{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:calc(49%);
 font-size: 15px;
 
}

.b-logo-secondary-text 
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height:1.8;
}

.b-org-info 
{ 
 height:2em;
 border:1px solid hsla(90,80%,50%,1);
  font:normal 100%/1 sans-serif;
  color:hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
  flex:1 1 29%;
}

.b-org-info__address {
  float:left;
  display: block;
  width:calc(25%);
  text-align:right;
 line-height:2;
}

.b-org-info__hint { 
 float:right;
  width:calc(70%);
  color: #ffff00;
  text-align:left;
 line-height:2;
}
```

```html
<header class="b-header flex">
    <a href="" class="b-second-logo">ссылка_1</a>
    <a href="" class="b-logo">ссылка_2</a>

    <div class="b-logo-text">
    <strong> Заголовок </strong>
    <div class="b-logo-secondary-text">Заголовок 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="b-org-info">
     <div class="b-org-info__address">Адрес : </div>
     <div class="b-org-info__hint">Пушкина 15</div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Указывайте потомкам размеры методом flex:1 1 размер;